# Vert.x httpClient/webClient process response chunk by chunk or as stream

Tags: jvm, vert.x

I have application with vert.x and asyncHttpClient. I want to replace asyncHttpClient with vert.x httpClient (webClient), but i need to have ability to process response by chunks or by small parts of data (like org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHandler in AsyncHttpClient) or like a stream. Is it possible? I look at custom BodyCodec, but i can`t understand data flow in custom WriteStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily with Vert.x Web Client which is designed for buffering responses.

However you can do this with the Vert.x Http Client:

```
client.request(HttpMethod.GET, "some-uri", ar1 -> {

  if (ar1.succeeded()) {
    HttpClientRequest request = ar1.result();
    request.send(ar2 -> {
      HttpClientResponse response = ar2.result();
      response.handler(buffer -> {
        System.out.println("Received a part of the response body: " + buffer);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It's that what i need